# How to update a field with random data?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a new varchar(10) field in a database with 1000+ records.  I'd like to update the table so I can have random data in the field.  I'm looking for a SQL solution.

I know I can use a cursor, but that seems inelegant.

MS-SQL 2000,BTW

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
update MyTable Set RandomFld =  CONVERT(varchar(10), NEWID())
```

Comment: With this addition
UPDATE table SET field = CONVERT(varchar(10), LEFT(NEWID(), 10))

Comment: Sorry, don't have SQLServer running here, so I couldn't test it.

Comment: This assigns the same randomm value to every entry. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94906/how-do-i-return-random-numbers-as-a-column-in-sql-server-2005#94951 will randomize each row, and works in SQL2000

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to adapt something [like this](http://www.mitchelsellers.com/blogs/articletype/articleview/articleid/249/creating-random-sql-server-test-data.aspx) to load a test dataset of values, depending on what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, if you are just doing this for testing or one time use I would say that an elegant solution is not really necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the first 10 characters of an md5 checksum of the current timestamp and a random number?

Answer (score 1):

Something like (untested code):

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET yourfield= CHAR(32+ROUND(RAND()*95,0));
```

Obviously, concatenate more random characters if you want up to ten chars.
It's possible that the query optimizer might set all fields to the same value; in that case, I would try

```
SET yourfield=LEFT(yourfield,0)+CHAR…
```

to trick the optimizer into recalculating each time the expression.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one time thing just to get data into the system I really see no issue with using a cursor as much as I hate cursors they do have their place.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
UPDATE TBL SET Field = LEFT( CONVERT(varchar(255), @myid),10)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are in SQL Server you can use

```
CAST(RAND() as varchar(10))
```

**EDIT**: This will only work inside an iteration. As part of a multi-row insert it will use the same RAND() result for each row.