# What am I doing wrong when using RAND() in MS SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server, random

I'm trying to select a random 10% sampling from a small table.  I thought I'd just use the RAND() function and select those rows where the random number is less than 0.10:

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable
WHERE SomeColumn='SomeCondition' AND
      RAND() < 0.10
```

But I soon discovered that RAND() always returns the same number!  Reminds me of this [xkcd cartoon](http://xkcd.com/221/).

[image]

OK, no problem, the RAND function takes a seed value.  I will be running this query periodically, and I want it to give different results if I run it on a different day, so I seed it with a combination of the date and a unique row ID:

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable
WHERE SomeColumn='SomeCondition' AND
      RAND(CAST(GETDATE) AS INTEGER) + RowID) < 0.10
```

I still don't get any results!  When I show the random numbers returned by RAND, I discover that they're all within a narrow range.  It appears that getting a random number from RAND requires you to use a random seed.  If I had a random seed in the first place, I wouldn't need a random number!

I've seen the previous discussions related to this problem:

[SQL Server Random Sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52964/sql-server-random-sort)
[How to request a random row in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412/how-to-request-a-random-row-in-sql)

They don't help me.  TABLESAMPLE works at the page level, which is great for a big table but not for a small one, and it looks like it applies prior to the WHERE clause.  TOP with NEWID doesn't work because I don't know ahead of time how many rows I want.

Anybody have a solution, or at least a hint?

**Edit:** Thanks to AlexCuse for a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163604/what-am-i-doing-wrong-when-using-rand-in-ms-sql-server-2005#163843) which works for my particular case. Now to the larger question, how to make RAND behave?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This type of approach (shown by ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ) will not guarantee a 10% sampling.  It will only give you all rows where Rand() is evaluated to < .10 which will not be consistent.

Something like

```
select top 10 percent * from MyTable order by NEWID()
```

will do the trick.

**edit:** there is not really a good way to make RAND behave.  This is what I've used in the past (kludge alert - it kills you not being able to use Rand() in a UDF)

```
CREATE VIEW RandView AS 

SELECT RAND() AS Val

GO

CREATE FUNCTION RandomFloat()
RETURNS FLOAT
AS
BEGIN

RETURN (SELECT Val FROM RandView)

END
```

Then you just have `select blah, dbo.RandomFloat() from table` in your query.

Comment: An approximation to 10% was good enough for me, but your answer solves my immediate problem nicely. I should have thought to check for a PERCENT clause on TOP.

Answer (score 2):

If your table has a column (perhaps even the **rowid** column) that is numeric in the general sense, like integer, floating point or SQL numeric, please try the following:

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE SomeColumn='SomeCondition' AND 0*rowid+RAND() < 0.10
```

In order to evaluate `RAND()` once for *every row*, not once at *the start of your query*.

The query optimizer is to blame. Perhaps there is another way, but I believe this will work for you.

Comment: That method isn't working for me. I only have varchar and int, and I don't understand why int would behave different than numeric.

Comment: If it's the optimizer then it's very much like the cartoon!

Comment: Perhaps it's my fault, but saying "numeric" I meant any numeric type (integer, shortint, float, "SQL" numeric etc). Check my answer again, please.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
select * from SomeTable
where rand(0*SomeTableID + cast(cast(newid() as binary(4)) as int)) <= 0.10
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you see this question?

[How do I return random numbers as a column in SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94906/how-do-i-return-random-numbers-as-a-column-in-sql-server-2005)

Adam posted a UDF you can use in place of Rand() that works much better.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work

```
SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT * FROM schema.MyTable ORDER BY NEWID()
```