# Random numbers from database

Tags: sql, random

**EDIT**: Duplicate of [How do I return random numbers as a column in SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94906/how-do-i-return-random-numbers-as-a-column-in-sql-server-2005)

Hello 
How can I generate random numbers in mssql server 2005.

for example: when I select 500rows from table, each row must have one generated random number, numbers must be generated at runtime

UPDATE: I need the fastest method, generate numbers from large tables, datepart, same magic computations is realatively slow with big amount of rows

UPDATE thanks for answers, but o finally used this solution

```
SELECT ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % 10 - 5 AS Random
```

for random numbers from -5 to 5 and bonus is approximately the same number of occurances for each number

Comment: Does each column need a UNIQUE random number??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 500
    CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARBINARY(16), NEWID()))
FROM
    dbo.MyTable
```

Comment: Your query produces negative numbers, which is why I didn't vote it up.

Comment: I didn't realize that negative numbers were bad :P ... you could wrap it in ABS()

Answer (score 3):

I love this trick, its awesome ...

```
-- 500 random numbers from 0 to 499 
select top 500 ABS(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY) AS int)) % 500 from sysobjects
```

Comment: +1. I've deleted my incorrect answer!

Comment: I'm sad... I answered this first, but got no +1 :'(

Comment: @Timothy, I just voted you up for good measure, I swear I didn't see your answer when I posted mine and I have the mod trick

Comment: LOL, I know... the timing is really close... I was only joking (and cried for only like 15 seconds anyway)

Answer (score 0):

[easy google](http://www.google.com/search?q=mssql+2005+generate+random): [1](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2004/11/22/2927.aspx) [2](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/29/sql-server-random-number-generator-script-sql-query/) ...

---

> Returning Random Numbers in a SELECT statement

As it is implemented, **the RAND() function in SQL Server doesn't let you return a different random number per row** in your SELECT statement. For example, if you execute this:

```
SELECT Rand() as RandomNumber, *
FROM Northwind..Customers
```

You will see the same number over and over.  However, sometimes, you may want to return a randomly generated number per line in your SELECT.   Here's one way to do that, in SQL Server 2000, using a UDF.

First, we need to create a View that returns a single random number:

```
CREATE VIEW vRandNumber
AS
SELECT RAND() as RandNumber
```

The view is necessary because normally in a UDF we cannot use the rand() function, because that would make the function non-determistic.  We can trick the UDF to accepting a random number by using a View.

Once that is set up, we can then create our function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION RandNumber()
RETURNS float
AS
  BEGIN
  RETURN (SELECT RandNumber FROM vRandNumber)
  END
```

Finally, you can use this function in any SELECT to now return a random number between 0 and 1 per row:

```
SELECT dbo.RandNumber(), *
FROM Northwind..Customers
```

You can get even fancier in your RandNumber function by accepting a seed if you like, or allowing for range parameters like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION RandNumber2(@Min int, @Max int)
RETURNS float
AS
 BEGIN
 RETURN @Min + (select RandNumber from RetRandNumber) * (@Max-@Min)
 END
```

Comment: Is it just me or will these simple easy-to-google answers end up clogging up SO and make it harder te find the valuable hard-to-google information?

Comment: True, easy to Google... but the solutions you found are much more complicated than they need to be.

Comment: Looking at the answers I guess that's valid.. Had just been seeing a few too many trivial questions lately.. On closer inspection this isnt one of them.

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to know why you want the random number.  For example if you just want to sort the results randomly you can do ORDER BY NEWID() and not worry about generating the random number at all.  If you really need the random number later, use @Tim quoted solution.