# How to update table column with random value from a list of values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to update a table with random values from a specific list of values. I got as far as the code below which does not work because the same value is being inserted into each row:

```
UPDATE [Post]
SET UserID = (
    /** If I run this select statement independently then I get random value each time but not in this update statement **/
    SELECT TOP (1) UserID 
    FROM
    [User]
    WHERE UserID IN (1,3,4,7)
    ORDER BY NEWID()
)
WHERE
    UserID <> 10 AND UserID <> 11
```

I tried looking at using `ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%4 + 5` but generates any number between 1 and 4 which is not what I want. It has to be one of the values of `1,3,4,7` or any other list of specific values.

Comment: you tried this `TOP(ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%4 + 5)

Comment: I think this can only be done using a while loop

Comment: this code won't work because  all rows of post table  will be updated with whatever random number is returned by inner select. e.g. if inner select gives 3 then all filtered rows on Post table  will be updated with 3.

Comment: You should try to update one row at a time.

Comment: @AmitKumar I am heading that way but its so slow for thousands of records

Comment: @volumeone, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003028/how-can-i-fill-a-column-with-random-numbers-in-sql-i-get-the-same-value-in-ever, Does it help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to do it using a CURSOR like this:

```
DECLARE PostCursor CURSOR 
FOR SELECT PostID FROM dbo.Post WHERE UserID <> 10 AND UserID <> 11 FOR UPDATE
OPEN PostCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM PostCursor 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

     UPDATE dbo.Post 
     SET 
        UserID = (
        SELECT TOP (1) UserID FROM 
        [dbo].[User]
        WHERE UserID IN (1,3,4,7)
        ORDER BY NEWID()
        )

    WHERE CURRENT OF PostCursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM PostCursor
END
CLOSE PostCursor
DEALLOCATE PostCursor
```

Answer (score 2):

Demo on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ce8da595416bc7c15e0682f5da08307a)

You can use `CROSS APPLY` combine with `NEWID()` to get random value each row being updated

```
DECLARE @TempTable Table(Id int)
INSERT INTO @TempTable
VALUES(90), (80), (70)

UPDATE t1
SET Id = t2.Id
FROM @TempTable t1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM(VALUES(1), (3), (4), (7))t(Id) WHERE t1.Id = t1.Id ORDER BY NEWID()) t2

SELECT * FROM @TempTable
```

[image]

Comment: This only works if the values in TempTable are unique. In my table the values are like `100, 100, 100, 100` because a `UserID` can make as many posts as they want. It does not work in this fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=50bc682cfcb0e18c89ab7c654f7c75e4

Comment: @volumeone use some other column in the _inner_ `WHERE` clause. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0096fd62af4e407abc443f43e5d42ca3