# How to update one column's multiple rows with multiple values in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a data table like the name as `data_table` and sample data are like below

| id | name | type | temp_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | n1 | t1 |  |
| 1 | n1 | t1 |  |
| 1 | n1 | t1 |  |
| 1 | n1 | t1 |  |
| 2 | n1 | t1 |  |
| 2 | n1 | t1 |  |
| 2 | n1 | t1 |  |
| 2 | n1 | t1 |  |
| 2 | n1 | t1 |  |

I would like to `update` , `temp_id` columns with specific unique values. Like below.

| id | name | type | temp_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | n1 | t1 | 1001 |
| 1 | n1 | t1 | 1002 |
| 1 | n1 | t1 | 1003 |
| 1 | n1 | t1 | 1004 |
| 2 | n1 | t1 | 1005 |
| 2 | n1 | t1 | 1006 |
| 2 | n1 | t1 | 1007 |
| 2 | n1 | t1 | 1008 |
| 2 | n1 | t1 | 1009 |

Comment: Please go through the URL [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003028/how-can-i-fill-a-column-with-random-numbers-in-sql-i-get-the-same-value-in-ever

Comment: Which MySQL version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE test
SELECT 1 id, 'n1' name, 't1' type, CAST(NULL AS UNSIGNED) temp_id UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'n1', 't1', NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'n1', 't1', NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'n1', 't1', NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'n1', 't1', NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'n1', 't1', NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'n1', 't1', NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'n1', 't1', NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'n1', 't1', NULL ;
SELECT * FROM test;
```

> ```
> Records: 9  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

| id | name | type | temp_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | n1 | t1 | *null* |
| 1 | n1 | t1 | *null* |
| 1 | n1 | t1 | *null* |
| 1 | n1 | t1 | *null* |
| 2 | n1 | t1 | *null* |
| 2 | n1 | t1 | *null* |
| 2 | n1 | t1 | *null* |
| 2 | n1 | t1 | *null* |
| 2 | n1 | t1 | *null* |

```
SET @start_from := 1000;
UPDATE test
SET temp_id = (@start_from := @start_from + 1);
```

> ```
> Rows matched: 9  Changed: 9  Warnings: 1
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM test;
```

| id | name | type | temp_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | n1 | t1 | 1001 |
| 1 | n1 | t1 | 1002 |
| 1 | n1 | t1 | 1003 |
| 1 | n1 | t1 | 1004 |
| 2 | n1 | t1 | 1005 |
| 2 | n1 | t1 | 1006 |
| 2 | n1 | t1 | 1007 |
| 2 | n1 | t1 | 1008 |
| 2 | n1 | t1 | 1009 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/gOZwOMOE)

Comment: I'm using `update data_table , (select  @row_id:=1000 ) t  
set temp_id= (@row_id:=@row_id+1);` which puts the SET statement in the UPDATE statement.

Comment: @blabla_bingo This is safe in current task (any enumeration needed) but unusable in the case when some definite ordering of rows enumeration needed (for example, when in current task you'd guarantee that the numbers for `id=1` should be lower than for `id=2`). Multiple-table UPDATE does not allow ORDER BY.. Of course there is a trick when the variable initialization is placed into WHERE.

Answer (score 0):

Using CASE Expression:

You can use a CASE expression to set different values for each row you want to update. Here's an example:

```
UPDATE your_table
    SET column_to_update = 
    CASE 
        WHEN some_condition1 THEN new_value1
        WHEN some_condition2 THEN new_value2
        WHEN some_condition3 THEN new_value3
        -- Add more conditions and new values as needed
        ELSE column_to_update
    END;
```

Comment: no ''some_condition"