# Generate unique 9 digits values

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table as shown below:

```
Group           
---------------------------     
Id  Num         Name    Age
---------------------------
1   424000000   Damine  22
2   324000000   Arshley 18
3   276000000   Tita    20
4   424000000   Helen   21
5   424000000   Mary    19
6   324000000   Kathe   20
7   324000000   Mark    18
8   276000000   Phill   22
```

i want to make the Num col unique so i need to generate 9 digit numeric random values for the duplicates.

please help, Thanks

Comment: is `000000001` an acceptable value? or is `100000000` the smallest allowable 'random' value?

Comment: Does the num column always have six zeros as the last six digits? Do you have to retain the values that are currently unique?

Comment: Does the number need to be *random* or *unique*?

Comment: @Marc, no it is not an acceptable value.

Comment: @Aaron, the number needs to be unique

Comment: To clarify - custom id's have been covered many times and the answer is invariably **this is a bad idea**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I generate random number for each row in a TSQL Select?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045138/how-do-i-generate-random-number-for-each-row-in-a-tsql-select)

Comment: @Jaydee, yes, i need to retain the values that are unique and the last six digits does not have to be zeros

Answer (score 3):

you set the num column as an identity field with a seed like 100000000 or just set the num field to an identity and print its value with an overloaded tostring method

Update: doing this (adding an identity column) through Management Studio will drop and recreate the table, which is not recommended on a very very large table

Comment: How do you do this if the table already exists? There is no DDL for this, and you know that if you do it through Management Studio, it drops and re-creates the table, right? This might be okay in some cases but it can be disastrous if the table is large.

Comment: @Aaron, We dont know why he created a table without an identity field in the first place, but its better to recreate the table with an IDENTITY field (which is always unique) than trying to create customly implemented uniqueness.Not having a unique IDENTITY field and trying to calculate a unique number into a column has its performance issues and not always 100% guaranteed IMHO

Comment: That may be true but I think it is dangerous to suggest this approach without the warning that doing it through Management Studio can take your production application offline.

Comment: @Aaron, you're right, but since gina told us that the table is about 800 rows long i think its not going to be an issue, anyway ill do an update on the answer

Comment: My point is that someone else coming along later might look at the answer and think it's a good idea for them, too. They might miss details about Gina's specific situation with this one table.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH u AS
(
 SELECT *, new_num = ROW_NUMBER() 
  OVER (PARTITION BY Num ORDER BY Id)
  FROM dbo.Group
)
UPDATE u SET Num += new_num - 1
FROM u
WHERE new_num > 1;
```

Comment: i just tried that and got this error msg : 

A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.

Comment: What is `SELECT @@VERSION;`, how many rows in the table, are there indexes on any of the columns...

Comment: there are over 800 rows and there is an index on the id col. thanks

Comment: And what does `SELECT @@VERSION;` yield?

Comment: it yields:  Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (Intel X86)   Apr  2 2010 15:53:02   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition on Windows NT 6.1 <X86> (Build 7600: )

Comment: You're running the original release. A lot of these "server error" problems have been solved since RTM, you should install Service Pack 1. http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=20302

Answer (score 0):

Not tested... but something like that...

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(9), RIGHT(NEWID(), 9)) AS [MyID] 
WHERE 
    LEFT([MyID], 1) NOT LIKE '0';
```