# creating a random number using MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to know is there a way to select randomly generated number between 100 and 500 along with a select query.

Eg: `SELECT name, address, random_number FROM users`

I dont have to store this number in db and only to use it to display purpose.

I tried it something like this, but it can't get to work..

```
SELECT name, address, FLOOR(RAND() * 500) AS random_number FROM users
```

Hope someone help me out.
Thank you

Comment: Please visit this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045138/how-do-i-generate-random-number-for-each-row-in-a-tsql-select

Answer (score 160, accepted):

This should give what you want:

```
FLOOR(RAND() * 401) + 100
```

Generically, `FLOOR(RAND() * (<max> - <min> + 1)) + <min>` generates a number between `<min>` and `<max>` inclusive.

**Update**

This full statement should work:

```
SELECT name, address, FLOOR(RAND() * 401) + 100 AS `random_number` 
FROM users
```

Comment: how I use this code. I tried like this - FLOOR(RAND() * 401) + 100 as number, but not working

Comment: NOTE: I dont have a column named 'number' in my db. This must be dynamically generated column. is it posible?

Comment: @EdHeal Actually I think `round()` will give a non-uniform distribution.

Comment: @Jack it is not working with my real query.. why is it? when selecting only 'random_number' its working.

Comment: There is an error message when running this with my real query

Comment: I use this with my real code something like this.... $q = "SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * 401) + 100 AS like, tcs.tutor_id AS tid, tcs.category_id AS cid, tcs.subject_id AS sid,.....and so on

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24269/discussion-between-tharanga-nuwan-and-jack)

Comment: Better store the result to a variable and use the variable if you have master slave replication. `SET @r=FLOOR(RAND() * 401) + 100`, then `SELECT @r`.

Comment: @ElgsQianChen what use-case would that be for? replication is only for updating statements, so not sure how that would be useful :)

Comment: `RAND()`, `UUID()`, `NOW()` are indeterministic functions. The calling of such functions should be avoid from being written into the bin log for replication. For example. `INSERT INTO t SET ID=UUID();` will cause the value of the `ID` fields to be different on master and slaves. Instead it needs to be written as `SET @uuid:=UUID();`, and then `INSERT INTO t SET ID=@uuid;`, then run them in a single transaction. This will be replication safe. This is a bit off topic for this question. It doesn't say your answer has any problem. :)

Comment: @ElgsQianChen right, didn't think about that, interesting :)

Comment: To always get a value between 100 and 500 you have to do  `FLOOR(RAND() * 400.9999...999)) + 100`. If you replace `RAND()` with `1` (a possible value) in your code you'll see it returns `501`. That may or may not be a problem.

Comment: @Erk I don't think 1 is a possible value, the range should be [0, 1)

Comment: @Ja͢ck You are right! The documentation actually says: "Returns a random floating-point value v in the range 0 <= v < 1.0." Thanks for that! (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand)

Answer (score 11):

As `RAND` produces a number  0 <= v < 1.0 (see [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand)) you need to use `ROUND` to ensure that you can get the upper bound (500 in this case) and the lower bound (100 in this case)

So to produce the range you need:

```
SELECT name, address, ROUND(100.0 + 400.0 * RAND()) AS random_number
FROM users
```

Comment: This coding working like this - SELECT ROUND(100.0 + 400.0 * RAND()) AS random_number, but now working with my query

Comment: random_number column must be randomly generated column along with my query.

Comment: This method will make the first and last number less likely.

Answer (score 5):

Additional to this answer, create a function like

```
CREATE FUNCTION myrandom(
    pmin INTEGER,
    pmax INTEGER
)
RETURNS INTEGER(11)
DETERMINISTIC
NO SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
BEGIN
  RETURN floor(pmin+RAND()*(pmax-pmin));
END;
```

and call like

`SELECT myrandom(100,300);`

This gives you random number between 100 and 300

Answer (score 4):

these both are working nicely:

```
select round(<maxNumber>*rand())
```

---

```
FLOOR(RAND() * (<max> - <min> + 1)) + <min> // generates a number
between <min> and <max> inclusive.
```

Answer (score 3):

You could create a random number using `FLOOR(RAND() * n) as randnum` (n is an integer), however if you do not need the same random number to be repeated then you will have to somewhat store in a temp table. So you can check it against with `where randnum not in (select * from temptable)`...

Answer (score 0):

This is correct formula to find integers from `i` to `j` where `i <= R <= j`

```
FLOOR(min+RAND()*(max-min))
```

Comment: This is wrong, it will never produce j (or max). It produces a number i <= R < j.

Comment: Should be: `FLOOR(min+RAND()*(max-min+1))`