# How to generate random and unique integer on sql field?

Tags: sql, sql-server, random, identity

I have a table with a integer primary key. The inserts to the table are made via a stored procedure.

I want to use random numbers for the primary key, for example:

```
ID
4345,
3432,
6686,
8556
```

The length of the number must be the same for each row.

I tried using `identity` specifications but it is incremental, not random.

Comment: Why do you want that?

Comment: `ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))`?

Comment: `SUBSTRING(CAST(ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) AS VARCHAR),0,5)` and retrying until the id doesnt exits. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two options for that -

Get a random value and do retries - 
[creating a random number using MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798640/creating-a-random-number-using-mysql)

Use auto increment which produces unique values but the results are not random - 
[How to set initial value and auto increment in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485668/how-to-set-initial-value-auto-increment-in-mysql)