# mysql - how to get a random time (not date) between two time ranges

Tags: mysql, random, time

I am trying to work out how to return a random time between 2 time ranges.
For example, get a random time between 15:00:00 and 22:00:00

So far, I have - but don't know how to limit it

```
select sec_to_time(floor(15 + (rand() * 86401)))
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(
          FLOOR(
             TIME_TO_SEC('15:00:00') + RAND() * (
                  TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('22:00:00', '15:00:00'))
             )
          )
        );
```

Calculate in seconds. Then add a random number that is in the range of seconds between `15:00:00` and `22:00:00` to `15:00:00`. Then convert the seconds back to a time value.

- for more information on the used functions, see [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

Comment: I know it's been 2.5 years since you posted this answer, but you managed to solve a problem I couldn't figure out on my own. Thanks @fancyPants !

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
select FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('<starting_date_in_date_format>') + FLOOR(0 + (RAND() * UNIX_TIMESTAMP('<ending_date_in_date_format>'))) from dual;
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `select FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('<starting_date_in_date_format>') + FLOOR(RAND() * (UNIX_TIMESTAMP('<ending_date_in_date_format>') - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('<starting_date_in_date_format>')))` because rand should be multiplied by distance between unix ending and starting timestamp but not unix ending timestamp itself. Unix timestamp is just an integer so we are basically generating random number from range: `range_start + floor(rand() * (range_end - range_start))`.

Answer (score 1):

Logic is simple,

1. Get difference between 2 times.
2. Generate random number between those 2 times(numbers)
3. You can direct generate time in Minutes or Seconds.

Following is example for getting Random Hour,

```
select Round((FLOOR(RAND() * (TIME_TO_SEC('15:00:00') - TIME_TO_SEC('22:00:00') + 1)) + TIME_TO_SEC('22:00:00')) / 3600,0)
```

EDIT : [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/41a7e/8)

For reference see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798640/creating-a-random-number-using-mysql)