# Select a Random row in realm table

Tags: android, realm

I want to select a random row from the realm table. Something like -

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this would do, yes?

```
Random random = new Random();
RealmResults<YourTable> list = realm.where(YourTable.class).findAll();
YourTable yourTable = list.get(random.nextInt(list.size()));
```

Comment: Wouldn't this first read all data. I have 100 thousand records in my table.

Comment: No, RealmResults are lazy-loaded. It is slightly less effective than the SQLite variant because the core still has to do the query, but the memory usage in Java is still only 1 object.

Comment: You only execute the query, but you don't actually evaluate the results. You only evaluate 1 random element within that list. So no, this would not read all the data, only 1 data.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to do:

Do you want to get a random row from a table?
Or A (random) row from a random table?

I guess you mean the former:
If you have an id in your table, you could just:

```
SELECT * FROM table b WHERE id = FLOOR(RAND() * (3 - 0 + 1)) + 0
```

You should place a min and max here like so:

```
FLOOR(RAND() * (<max> - <min> + 1)) + <min>
```

(as found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14798686/4716861))

Comment: This question is for Realm not of sqlite

Comment: You quoted sql code, so I presumed you want to solve it with a sql statement inside realm. Downvote uncalled-for ...

Comment: I didn't down voted any answer on SO. I never have and I never will.

Comment: Oh, sorry that I assumied it was you. :/

Answer (score 0):

**SWIFT 5**

I do it this way and it works perfect:

```
let results      = realm.objects(MyObject.self)        // Get all the objects
let randomIndex  = Int.random(in: 0 ..< results.count) // Get a random number within the number of objects returned
let randomObject = results[randomIndex]                // Get a random object
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it in .NET, takes 7ms for 70K entries.

```
    public IEnumerable<Entry> GetRandomEntries()
    {
        var randomizer = new Random();
        var entries = GetRealmInstance().All<Entry>().AsEnumerable();
        // Takes random entries and shuffles them to break the natural order
        var randomEntries = entries
            .OrderBy(x => randomizer.Next(0, DbQueryRandomEntriesLimit))
            .Take(DbQueryRandomEntriesLimit)
            .OrderBy(entry => entry.GetHashCode());

        return randomEntries;
    }
```

> I use AsEnumerable() to allow using .Select in LINQ

Answer (score -1):

```
String query =String.format("SELECT * FROM realm ORDER BY %d LIMIT 1", random());
databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        database = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = database.execSQL(query);
```

It works assuming that you have a class DatabaseHelper which extends SQLiteOpenHelper

Comment: This question is for Realm not of sqlite