# How come RAND() is messing up in SQL subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql

My goal is to select a random business and then with that business' id get all of their advertisements. I am getting unexpected results from my query. The number of advertisement rows returned is always what I assume is the value of "SELECT id FROM Business ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1". I have 3 businesses and only 1 business that has advertisement rows (5 of them) yet it always displays between 1-3 of the 5 advertisements for the same business.

```
SELECT * FROM Advertisement WHERE business_id=(SELECT id FROM Business ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) ORDER BY priority
```

**Business TABLE:**
[image: Business TABLE]

**Advertisement TABLE:**
[image: Advertisement TABLE]

**Data for Advertisement and Business tables:**

```
INSERT INTO `Advertisement` (`id`, `business_id`, `image_url`, `link_url`, `priority`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'http://i64.tinypic.com/2w4ehqw.png', 'https://www.dennys.com/food/burgers-sandwiches/spicy-sriracha-burger/', 1),
(2, 1, 'http://i65.tinypic.com/zuk1w1.png', 'https://www.dennys.com/food/burgers-sandwiches/prime-rib-philly-melt/', 2),
(3, 1, 'http://i64.tinypic.com/8yul3t.png', 'https://www.dennys.com/food/burgers-sandwiches/cali-club-sandwich/', 3),
(4, 1, 'http://i64.tinypic.com/o8fj9e.png', 'https://www.dennys.com/food/burgers-sandwiches/bacon-slamburger/', 4),
(5, 1, 'http://i68.tinypic.com/mwyuiv.png', 'https://www.dennys.com/food/burgers-sandwiches/the-superbird/', 5);

INSERT INTO `Business` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Test Dennys'),
(2, 'Test Business 2'),
(3, 'Test Business 3');
```

Comment: If I recall correctly, in order to order randomly you need to `SELECT RAND() AS r .... ORDER BY r`; otherwise, `ORDER BY RAND()` orders by a single result from `RAND()` similar to `ORDER BY 1` or `ORDER BY NOW()`. _Of course, that creates a problem with using that subquery._

Comment: I am not sure I understand. The "SELECT id FROM Business ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1" seems to work properly when by itself (returns number between 1 and 3 in my case for the 3 businesses). I don't get why this number isn't properly being assigned to business_id outside of subquery.

Comment: Can you please post data in which you are trying the query, as I have tried its returning 5 of 5 from the advertisement.

Comment: Can you post the query you are using? I will try it and see if it works for me.

Comment: I edited OP with the data.

Comment: you may find this [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798640/creating-a-random-number-using-mysql) question useful

Comment: @JasonFel if you execute `SELECT id FROM Business ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1` repeatedly, each execution will get a separate value from `RAND()`. What happens if you try `SELECT id FROM Business ORDER BY RAND(), id` (with no limit) repeatedly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're assuming your query does something it doesn't do.

`(SELECT id FROM Business ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1)` isn't materialized at the beginning of the query.  It's evaluated *for each row*... so for each row, we're testing whether that business_id matches the result of a newly-executed instance of the subquery.  More thorough test data (more than one business included) should reveal this.

You need to materialize the result into a derived table, then join to it.

```
SELECT a.* 
  FROM Advertisement a
  JOIN (
        SELECT (SELECT id 
                  FROM Business 
                 ORDER BY RAND() 
                 LIMIT 1) AS business_id
        ) b ON b.business_id = a.business_id;
```

The `( SELECT ... ) x` construct creates a temporary table that exists only for the duration of the query and uses the alias `x`.  Such tables can be joined just like real tables.

MySQL calls this a [Subquery in the `FROM` Clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/from-clause-subqueries.html).

Comment: Michael, does the `RAND()` use cause this behavior? Because in my experience, normally MySQL only evaluates a subquery for every row of the outer query when the subquery is a correlated one.

Comment: @Uueerdo, that's correct... but the normal behavior is what it is because of the fact that the optimizer tries to cache deterministic results of non-correlated subqueries, resolving them to constant values... `RAND()`, of course, isn't deterministic.  The query plan in this case will show a `select_type` of UNCACHEABLE SUBQUERY`.  Technically, I think it could be argued that you're always asking the server to evaluate a subquery for each row, but the optimizer is smart enough to rarely actually do it because the result of a non-correlated subquery would not typically vary.

Comment: This is brilliant. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try following query

```
SELECT * FROM Advertisement WHERE business_id = (select floor(1 + rand()* (select count(*) from Business)));
```

Comment: I tried and it gives me the same problem as my original query :(

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve rows in random order use SELECT * Instead Of Id and then query for its id.

```
SELECT * FROM Advertisement WHERE business_id=(SELECT ID FROM (SELECT * FROM Business ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) as table1)
```

In this case with your example data, only when rand returns 1 you get results.