# How to update rand number in sql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update rand number Resolve this my problem

update abc set postion=rand() where status = 1

Anybody can help

Comment: ```"UPDATE `abc` SET `position`='RAND(9)' WHERE `status`= 1"```

Comment: Try [This](https://database.guide/mysql-rand-function-generate-a-random-number-in-mysql/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [creating a random number using MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798640/creating-a-random-number-using-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

for random no in float type

SELECT name, FLOOR( RAND( ) * (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users)) + RAND() AS rand_no FROM users

for random no in integer type

SELECT name, FLOOR( RAND( ) * (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users)) + 100 AS rand_no FROM users