# In SQL, any way to create SELECT for arbitrary numbers?

Tags: sql, mysql

I would like to have a query with a result like below:

```
1000
2000
3000
```

or

```
1
3
5
```

so on..I want to control results from lists for instance.

```
SELECT 1 — I know that I can use SELECT like this for one result line but..
```

and want to use the result for other queries like below:

```
INSERT user (number) SELECT …
```

I want to have users with number of 1000, 2000, 3000 …

Actually, I asked this question in order to create test-data, sorry for unclarity..

Suppose that there is a table as below:

```
create table student
(
    id         bigint auto_increment
        primary key,
    name       varchar(255) null,
    age       integer
);
```

and tests are for `age`.

so I want to do like below:
I think it is incorrect..

```
INSERT INTO student (`name`, `age)
VALUES
— from here
SELECT ‘hoge’, …? or whatever
— any good expressions??
```

instead of

```
INSERT INTO student (`name`, `age)
VALUES
(‘hoge’, 10),
(‘hoge’, 20),
(‘hoge’, 30),
…
(‘hoge’, 100),
(‘hoge’, 200)
```

and the part of `age` hopefully is easily changeable.

In Python, comprehensive expression like this..

```
‘hoge’, age for age in [10,20,…]
```

Comment: Are you asking for the [VALUES statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/values.html)?

Comment: Can you elaborate little more on the question. If you are looking for a new table with this result or just a select statement. How many rows you want and so on.

Comment: There's a great GitHub code which creates the typical `GENERATE_SERIES` function that we know for example from PostgreSQL in MySQL. This code can be used for all you want (select, insert...). Here the link to the GitHub site: https://github.com/gabfl/mysql_generate_series. And here I created an example based on your question to generate the numbers 1000,2000,3000 etc.: https://dbfiddle.uk/FCgLrPBZ

Comment: Use recursive CTE. https://dbfiddle.uk/wgBnNw8U

Comment: If mariadb : https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sequence-storage-engine/

Comment: If you already know that you can use `SELECT` for this, what's the problem in using it?

Comment: So you want to insert rows into `student` table where the value for column `age` is a [random number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798640/creating-a-random-number-using-mysql), correct?

Comment: no I want to control the `age` numbers,  including sometime random numbers

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question properly.

But if you are looking for a select statement that generates a sequence without initializing variables;
the below code might help.

```
with recursive rnums as (
  select 1 as n
      union all
  select n+1 as n from rnums
      where n < 10
  )

select n*1000 as n_ from rnums;
```

Let us know if you are looking for something else.

Comment: Concatenation seems to be not correct. The output datatype is string in this case.. `n*1000` seems to be more correct. Also you may generate needed values in CTE immediately, this removes excess and unneeded calculations.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I make my post clearer…sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

Hope below query idea can help.
Consider you have student table with below inserted row:

```
create table student
(
    id         bigint auto_increment
        primary key,
    email      varchar(255) null,
    department varchar(255) null,
    name       varchar(255) null
);
    
INSERT INTO student ( email, department, name) VALUES ( 'john@yaoo.com', 'asd', 'John');
INSERT INTO student ( email, department, name) VALUES ( 'rocky@yahoo.com', 'this is test message', 'Rocky');
INSERT INTO student ( email, department, name) VALUES ( 'forhad@yaoo.com', 'THis is test message1', 'Forhad');
INSERT INTO student ( email, department, name) VALUES ( 'forhad@yaoo.com', 'THis is test message1', 'Forhad');
INSERT INTO student ( email, department, name) VALUES ( 'john@yaoo.com', 'asd', 'John');
INSERT INTO student ( email, department, name) VALUES ( 'rocky@yahoo.com', 'this is test message', 'Rocky');
```

Now you have another table `student_number`. There you can copy data from `student` with a number starting from 1000.

```
create table student_number
(
    id         bigint auto_increment
        primary key,
    email      varchar(255) null,
    name       varchar(255) null,
    number     int null
);

INSERT INTO student_number (email, name, number)
SELECT email, name, (@row := @row + 1000)  AS number
FROM student
JOIN
(SELECT @row := 0) r
```

Comment: You are adding 1000 to your @row. Doesn't it give output as 1001,1002,1003...? instead of 1000,2000,3000.... And looks like he wants this without dependency on a table

Comment: yes , thanks to correct me , but i am not sure weather he wants this without dependency on a table

Comment: Thank you for your answer!. sorry for my poor question, I edited for clarity.

Comment: @kensuke1984 good day, if it work for you kindly accept the answer and give some positive votes, it will inspire me to contribute more! pls