# Naming grouped sets in tsql

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, group-by

Is it possible to add a group name to a grouped set in `T-SQL`

```
Select Class, Category, Gender,Count(1) as Total, 'GroupNameHere' from PersonTable
Group By Class, Category, Gender
```

I want that every grouped set is given a new name like mentioned below

**Actual Table**

```
Name     |    Class   |   Category   |   Gender   |   Address   |   ZipCode
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
ABC      |      2     |     Cat 1    |     M      |  Some Add.. |   10125
XYZ      |      2     |     Cat 1    |     M      |  Some Add.. |   20554
AFF      |      3     |     Cat 3    |     M      |  Some Add.. |   24525
ASD      |      7     |     Cat 6    |     F      |  Some Add.. |   18892
GDS      |      7     |     Cat 6    |     F      |  Some Add.. |   17745
```

**Output**

```
Class |   Category   |   Gender   |   Total   |   GroupName
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
2     |     Cat 1    |     M      |     2     |   Group 1
3     |     Cat 3    |     M      |     1     |   Group 2
7     |     Cat 6    |     F      |     2     |   Group 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select Class, Category, Gender,Count(1) as Total,  'Group ' +CAST (Row_Number() over ( order by Class, Category, Gender) as varchar(10) )as GroupName 
from PersonTable 
Group By Class, Category, Gender
```

Comment: OMG, that was so simple... How can I forget `Row_Number()` for this purpose? Thanks for waking me up :D.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution by referring [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1045162/1584140). I can use [`NewId()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx) to generate a `GUID` based row id.

```
Select Class, Category, Gender,Count(1) as Total, 
'Group' + Convert(varchar(100),(ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())))) as GroupName from PersonTable
Group By Class, Category, Gender
```