# Generate random ID using cursor in SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, t-sql, cursor, dml

I want to generate a random id that uses table first and last name and a random number at the end of the login. I am not able to figure out how to use RAND function to add single random number at the end of name. Please help me. It will be appreciated. 
Thanks

```
DECLARE CUSTOMER_ID_CURSOR CURSOR 
STATIC 
FOR 
SELECT [first_name]+[last_name] as [ADMINISTRATOR ID] from administrators ;
OPEN CUSTOMER_ID_CURSOR;
FETCH NEXT FROM CUSTOMER_ID_CURSOR;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
FETCH NEXT FROM CUSTOMER_ID_CURSOR;
CLOSE CUSTOMER_ID_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE CUSTOMER_ID_CURSOR
```

Comment: Why is this tagged MySQL, SQL Server, and T-SQL?

Comment: Did you look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045138/how-do-i-generate-random-number-for-each-row-in-a-tsql-select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RAND() function is unsuitable for your purpose as it always produces the same number in a batch unless every row gets a new seed. Use the following:

```
SELECT [first_name]+[last_name] + 
  CAST(CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 10 as INT) AS CHAR(1))
  as [ADMINISTRATOR ID] from administrators ;
```

as your SELECT. It uses NEWID() to produce an UNIQUEIDENTIFIER for each row which is used as a seed for the RAND() function. The rest of the expression gets an integer between 1 and 10 and CASTs it as a CHAR(1) before adding it to your string.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve your goal through below query.

```
SELECT [first_name]+[last_name]
+cast (ROW_NUMBER() over(order by first_name ) as varchar(100))as [ADMINISTRATOR ID] 
from administrators ;
```

Comment: OP is looking for *single random number* at the end

Comment: How much random number that would you want to generate at the end of name.