# SQL Server 2012 Random string from a list

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

say I have 3 values, Bill, Steve, Jack. and I want to randomly update a table with those values, e.g.

```
Update contacts 
set firstname = ('Bill','Steve','Jack') 
where city = 'NY'
```

how do I randomize these values?

Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can do this with the following trick:

```
update c set name=ca.name
from contacts c
outer apply(select top 1 name 
            from (values('bill'),('steve'),('jack')) n(name)
            where c.id = c.id order by newid())ca;
```

`c.id = c.id` is just a dummy predicate that forces sql engine to call subquery for each outer row. Here is the fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8ecca/22

Comment: I am trying to make it into a function and posted question on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30332857/function-to-randomly-select-a-value-from-a-list-sql-server-2012 any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 13):

Here's some love using `choose`

```
with cte as (
   select *, (ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % 3) + 1 as n
   from contacts
   where city = 'NY'
)
update cte
set firstname = choose(n, 'Bill','Steve','Jack')
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like this

```
-- Storing the list of strings in a CTE

WITH PossibleValues AS 
( SELECT 'Bill' AS Name, 
          1 AS Number
  UNION SELECT 'Steve' AS NAME, 
         2 AS Number
  UNION SELECT 'Jack' AS NAME,
         3 AS Number
 )

UPDATE contacts
SET firstname = (SELECT Name
                          FROM PossibleValues
                          WHERE PossibleValues.Number = FLOOR(RAND()*(4-1)+1))
WHERE City = 'NY'
```

The `FLOOR(RAND()*(4-1)+1)` would generate a random number from 1 to 3 everytime you run the query. Therefore, you will be picking a random name every time.

Comment: Thanks, keep getting the last value (eg Jack)  for all rows. is there a way to randomize it for different rows in same run?

Answer (score 3):

This is addition answer using [Ben Thul answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30203233/1501497):

```
DECLARE @index INT
SELECT  @index = CAST(RAND() * 3 + 1 AS INT)
UPDATE contacts SET firstname = CHOOSE(@index,'Bill','Steve','Jack') WHERE city = 'NY'
```

Using RAND function will random values from 1 to 3. Then, based on resulted int value the CHOOSE function will pick values depending on the order/index of the given strings. In which 'Bill' is the index 1 then so on.

You can test the random int values by using below SQL script:

```
SELECT CAST(RAND() * 3 + 1 AS INT)
```

I have a weird issue if use the RAND directly to the query for example below:

```
SELECT CHOOSE( CAST(RAND() * 3 + 1 AS INT),'Bill','Steve','Jack')
```

There are instance that value is NULL.

Comment: You can format it better by select codes and click the `{}` button.

Answer (score 0):

This might answer your question:

[How do I generate random number for each row in a TSQL Select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045138/how-do-i-generate-random-number-for-each-row-in-a-tsql-select)

Use RAND to generate a number that determines which one to use.

Comment: I checked the link, but could not quite figure out how to use it, do you suggest a syntax for the query I have?

Answer (score 0):

Tried all suggestions above, ended up indexing to ID to generate a random index on a CHOOSE function

```
select
    lastname,
    choose( ((ID % 3)+1),'Bill','John','Mac') as firstname 
from contacts
```

where "3" is the number of items of your list.
It's not really random as it is indexed to your row id, but it's random enough so each row is different.

Answer (score 0):

```
select choose((FLOOR(RAND()*3)+1) , 'Bill','Steve','Jack')
```

Comment: Sometimes is NULL