# Function to Randomly Select a Value from a List SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am referring to
[SQL Server 2012 Random string from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30200105/sql-server-2012-random-string-from-a-list)

and would like to make it into a function. To the function, I pass the values to select from. Example Syntax:

RandomFrom('Bill','Steve','Jack',.....)

and it would randomly return one of them.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve the problem would be to create a User-Defined Table Type to contain the first names, and then pass that table to a Scalar-valued Function.

```
CREATE TYPE FirstNames AS TABLE (firstName varchar(50), RandomSeed varchar(128))
GO

DECLARE @myFirstNames as FirstNames
INSERT INTO @myFirstNames 
    SELECT 'Bill', NEWID()
    UNION SELECT 'Steve', NEWID()
    UNION SELECT 'Jack', NEWID()

SELECT * FROM @myFirstNames
```

Next, create a Scalar-valued Function that takes your new table type as a parameter.

```
CREATE FUNCTION RandomFirstName(@TableName dbo.FirstNames READONLY)
RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @name VARCHAR(50)

    SELECT TOP 1 @name = a.firstName 
    FROM @TableName a
    ORDER BY a.RandomSeed

    RETURN @name
END
```

Finally, call your function like so:

```
SELECT [dbo].[RandomFirstName] (@myFirstNames)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Contacts(id INT IDENTITY, name varchar(10))
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Contacts VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)
GO

CREATE VIEW vNames AS
SELECT * FROM (VALUES('Bill', NEWID()),('Steve',NEWID()),('Jack',NEWID())) Names(name, g)
GO

CREATE FUNCTION RandomFrom()
RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @name VARCHAR(10)

    SELECT TOP 1 @name = name
    FROM dbo.vNames
    ORDER BY g

    RETURN @name
END
GO

UPDATE dbo.Contacts SET name = dbo.RandomFrom()

SELECT * FROM dbo.Contacts
```

Output:

```
id  name
1   Bill
2   Jack
3   Jack
4   Bill
5   Steve
6   Steve
7   Steve
8   Jack
9   Bill
10  Bill
```

Comment: Thanks, Can I do it in one shot? i.e. pass to functions the values to choose from. I would be selecting on value for each time the function is run.

Comment: Did you see jax's answer?

Comment: Yes, I did. What I need is abitlity to do Select RandomFrom('Bill','Steve','Jack','John') without having to create a type or table.