# T-SQL SELECT Random varchar Value Without TempTable

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Other then creating a temp table is there an elegant way to select a random column value in an inline query

```
SELECT [Col1],
       [Col2],
       ChooseRandomlyFrom('Lateral', 'AP', 'AP Ext Rot', 'PA', 'PA Obl', 'PA Pbl Int Rot', 'Lateral', 'L5 S1', 'PA Navicular'),
       [Col3]
FROM [dbo].[MyTable]
```

I would like random per row in a query to generate a sample data set

Comment: Dynamic SQL: construct the statement as a string (using a CASE on a random int to pick the random column) then use sp_executeSQL to execute it.

Comment: The problem with things like `SELECT CASE CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4) % 2 WHEN 0 THEN 'Foo' WHEN 1 THEN 'Bar' END` will be that the expression gets expanded out to `SELECT CASE WHEN CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4) % 2 = 0 THEN 'Foo' ELSE CASE WHEN CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4) % 2 =1 THEN 'Bar' ELSE NULL END END` so the random number is evaluated multiple times not fixed.

Comment: Elegant?  use a table valued function pass in array of values and let the function randomly select a value? or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30200105/sql-server-2012-random-string-from-a-list?

Comment: Do you want random per row or random per select value?

Comment: @nimdil I would like random per row in a query to generate a sample data set

Comment: There's no *elegant* way to do that. I can think of clunky ways (tack on a `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID())` on both tables, fix things up with modulo), but no elegant ways.

Comment: @xQbert Will the CTE work on a per Row Basis ?

Comment: Check an updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it by using a variable with `CASE` expression in following:

```
DECLARE @rand INT
SET @rand = ABS(CONVERT(BIGINT,CONVERT(BINARY(8), NEWID()))) % 3 + 1 

SELECT [Col1],
       [Col2],
       CASE @rand 
        WHEN 1 THEN 'A'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'B'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'C'
        ELSE 'D'
       END AS RandColValue, 
       [Col3]
FROM [dbo].[MyTable]
```

Or you could achieve it without variable in following:

```
SELECT [Col1],
       [Col2],
       CASE ABS(CONVERT(BIGINT,CONVERT(BINARY(8), NEWID()))) % 3 + 1 
        WHEN 1 THEN 'A'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'B'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'C'
        ELSE 'D'
       END AS RandColValue, 
       [Col3]
FROM [dbo].[MyTable]
```

Comment: That's per-table, not per-row.

Comment: I believe this is still per Table

Comment: @JeroenMostert missed what OP want, now I got it, updated answer.

Comment: try running `SELECT CASE ABS(CONVERT(BIGINT,CONVERT(BINARY(8), NEWID()))) % 3 + 1 
        WHEN 1 THEN 'A'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'B'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'C'
       END AS RandColValue
into #t1
FROM master..spt_values`  and then `SELECT COUNT(*), RandColValue
FROM #t1
GROUP BY RandColValue`

Comment: @MartinSmith & Stanis Both of these kind of work but some of the rows return NULL, why is that ?

Comment: This is the issue I pointed out ages ago in the 2nd comment on the Q. I was hoping potential Answerers would avoid making this mistake but clearly not.

Comment: Fun Times with T-SQL !  Thanks Guys I think this is the closest to an answer given the original question.  The Solution atleast for my purposes is just to add an ELSE 'DEFAULT' to avoid the NULL issue.  Thanks for the help

Comment: Note that the distribution of "random" values you will be heavily skewed towards the last case (covered by `NULL`), and the other values won't be equally distributed either. If you don't care about that for testing purposes, great, but do not make the mistake of thinking your data is representative of a normal distribution.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Good Point For my Purposes it is ok but otherwise would be an issue the distribution is definitely not uniform

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by using a variable with **Choose** function

```
DECLARE @rand INT
SET @rand = ABS(CONVERT(BIGINT,CONVERT(BINARY(8), NEWID()))) % 3 + 1 

SELECT [Col1],
       [Col2],
       Choose(@rand,'A','B','C','D') AS RandColValue, 
       [Col3]
FROM [dbo].[MyTable]
```

Comment: The question is tagged 2008. This function is 2012+

Comment: @MartinSmith Interestingly enough doesn't seem to work on 2014 Either ?  But would make live allot easier