# Updating dates with random time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a `datetime` column, all of them at 12:00 am. Is there a way to update them with random hours, minutes to nearest 1/2 hour while keeping the same date(day) value?

```
Update Activities set ActivityDate = ....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one option using `dateadd`:

```
update Activities
set ActivityDate = DateAdd(minute, 
                           30 * (abs(checksum(NewId())) % 47), ActivityDate);
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6d084/1)

And [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1045162/1073631) a good post about generating random numbers.  Using that, multiple by 30 minutes to get to the nearest half hour.

Note, this uses `% 47` since there are 1440 minutes in a day -- that divides into 48 potential half hour segments in that same day.