# Case statement not correctly matching expected values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to generate some randomized data, and I've been using newid() to seed functions since it is called once for every row and is guaranteed to return a different result each time.  However I'm frequently getting values that are somehow not equal to any integers in the expected range.

I've tried a few variations, including a [highly upvoted one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045138/how-do-i-generate-random-number-for-each-row-in-a-tsql-select), but they all result in the same issue.  I've put it into a script that shows the problem:

```
declare @test table (id uniqueidentifier)
insert into @test
select newid() from sys.objects

select 
    floor(rand(checksum(id)) * 4),
    case isnull(floor(rand(checksum(id)) * 4), -1)
        when 0 then 0
        when 1 then 1
        when 2 then 2
        when 3 then 3
        when -1 then -1
        else 999
    end,
    floor(rand(checksum(newid())) * 4),
    case isnull(floor(rand(checksum(newid())) * 4), -1)
        when 0 then 0
        when 1 then 1
        when 2 then 2
        when 3 then 3
        when -1 then -1
        else 999
    end
from @test
```

I expect the results to always be in the range 0 to 3 for all four columns.  When the unique identifiers are retrieved from a table, the results are always correct (first two columns.)  Similarly, when they're output on the fly they're also correct (third column.)  But when they're compared on the fly to integers in a case statement, it often returns a value outside the expected range.

Here's an example, these are the first 20 rows when I ran it just now.  As you can see there are '999' instances in the last column that shouldn't be there:

```
0   0   3   1
3   3   3   1
0   0   3   3
3   3   2   999
1   1   2   999
3   3   2   1
2   2   0   999
0   0   0   0
3   3   2   0
1   1   3   999
3   3   0   999
2   2   2   2
1   1   3   0
2   2   3   0
3   3   1   999
0   0   1   999
3   3   1   1
0   0   0   3
3   3   0   999
0   0   1   0
```

At first I thought maybe the type coercion was different than I expected, and the result of rand() * int was a float not an int.  So I wrapped it all in floor to force it to be an int.  Then I thought perhaps there's an odd null value creeping in, but with my case statement a null would be returned as -1, and there are none.

I've run this one two different SQL Server 2012 SP1 instances, both give the same sort of results.

Comment: Before anyone asks: newid() returns a guid, checksum() calculates a checksum and returns a value between minInt and maxInt, rand() returns a random float value between 0 and 1, floor() returns an int nearest to but less than the parameter it was given.  They're standard functions in SQL Server, not anything I've created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the fourth column, `isnull(floor(rand(checksum(newid())) * 4), -1)` is being evaluated up to five times **for each row**. Once for each branch of the case. On each call the values can be different. So it can return 2, not match 1, 3 not match 2, 1 not match 3, 3 not match 4 fall to the else and return 999.

This can be seen if you get the execution plan, and look at the XML, there is a line [whitespace added.]:

```
<ScalarOperator ScalarString="
CASE WHEN isnull(floor(rand(checksum(newid()))*(4.000000000000000e+000)),(-1.000000000000000e+000))=(0.000000000000000e+000) THEN (0) 
    ELSE CASE WHEN isnull(floor(rand(checksum(newid()))*(4.000000000000000e+000)),(-1.000000000000000e+000))=(1.000000000000000e+000) THEN (1) 
        ELSE CASE WHEN isnull(floor(rand(checksum(newid()))*(4.000000000000000e+000)),(-1.000000000000000e+000))=(2.000000000000000e+000) THEN (2) 
            ELSE CASE WHEN isnull(floor(rand(checksum(newid()))*(4.000000000000000e+000)),(-1.000000000000000e+000))=(3.000000000000000e+000) THEN (3) 
                ELSE CASE WHEN isnull(floor(rand(checksum(newid()))*(4.000000000000000e+000)),(-1.000000000000000e+000))=(-1.000000000000000e+000) THEN (-1) 
                    ELSE (999) 
                END 
            END 
        END 
    END 
END
">
```

Placing the expression in a CTE seems to keep the recomputes from happening:

```
; WITH T AS (SELECT isnull(floor(rand(checksum(newid())) * 4), -1) AS C FROM @Test)
SELECT CASE C
        when 0 then 0
        when 1 then 1
        when 2 then 2
        when 3 then 3
        when -1 then -1
        else 999 END
FROM T
```

Comment: Well spotted, thanks!  Doesn't show up in the graphical execution plan except to say it's evaluating expressions.  I guess I should look at the text version instead from now on!