# What is the best way to anonymize ID values in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I got 2 tables in sql 2008

```
Table1
Id    Name Surname City   
1000  Alex White   London
1001  John Brown   Brussels
..

Table2
Id  Surgeon  Room  aId
1   Mike J.  A104  1000
2   Jack S.  C144  1001
...
```

And I have a query like:

```
Select a.Id,b.Id,
       a.Name,a.Surname,a.City,b.Surgeon,b.Room
into #results
from Table1 a
inner join Table2 b on a.Id = b.aId
```

What I want to do is to anonymize the a.Id and b.Id values for privacy, by using dummy ones instead of the real ones. I added a random mathematical operations before, like:

```
Select aId = a.Id * 22 / 5 + 14 * 2
      ,bId = b.Id * 12 / 4 + 7 * 3
       ...
```

but honestly I am not really happy what I am doing here and I am looking for a more professinal way to provide this. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Calculating an arbitrary number doesn't provide any more anonymity than 1001.

Comment: I just need dummy but logical ID values instead of the real ones for a.Id and b.Id

Comment: Do you need to be able to get the id back from the number?

Comment: Maybe [Dynamic Data Masking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt130841.aspx) will fit your needs?  It's only available with SQL 2016, but it's MS's out-of-the-box masking functionality.  You could try proprietary solutions as well.  Most offer a free trial.

Comment: no Zohar, I dont need

Comment: I gotta solve this issue in sql-2008

Comment: Maybe this can be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045138/how-do-i-generate-random-number-for-each-row-in-a-tsql-select

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to be sure the anonymized IDs are unique and you don't need to find a real ID based on an anonymized ID, you could use the [CheckSum()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms189788.aspx) or [HashBytes()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx) function with the strings from your Table1 and Table2:

```
Select aId = CheckSum(a.Name + a.Surname) % 10000
      ,bId = HashBytes('SHA1', b.Surgeon) % 10000
      ,a.Name,a.Surname,a.City,b.Surgeon,b.Room
into #results
from Table1 a
inner join Table2 b on a.Id = b.aId
```

If you need to be sure you have a unique value for each of the Id values in your table and you also need to find a real ID based on an anonymized ID, you can construct a lookup table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Anon
    (
    ID        INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    AnonID    UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NewID()
    );
```

this can then be used in queries where the actual ID should not be returned:

```
Select aID = Anona.AnonID,
       bID = Anonb.AnonID,
       a.Name,a.Surname,a.City,b.Surgeon,b.Room
   into #results
   from Table1 a inner join Table2 b on a.Id = b.aId
   inner join Anon Anona on a.Id = Anona.Id
   inner join Anon Anonb on b.Id = Anonb.Id
```

The Anon table would need to be maintained to ensure it contains all IDs from your Table1 and Table2.