# To Generate Random Numbers in Ms Sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need To Generate Random Numbers in Ms Sql server and the length is based on the configuration and it have to be achieved without using loop conditions.I should not hit any tables to get the required output.
 Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You mean there is variable with length?

Comment: Refer below URL : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045138/how-do-i-generate-random-number-for-each-row-in-a-tsql-select

Comment: @Whencesoever yes the length is variable.