# SQL Server 2012 : update a row with unique number

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have a table with 50k records. Now I want to update one column of the table with a random number. The number should be 7 digits.

I don't want to do that with procedure or loop.

```
PinDetailId  PinNo
--------------------
783          2722692
784          9888648
785          6215578
786          7917727
```

I have tried this code but not able to succeed. I need 7 digit number.

```
SELECT 
    FLOOR(ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) / 2147483647.0 * 3 + 1) rn, 
    (FLOOR(2000 + RAND() * (3000 - 2000) )) AS rn2 
FROM
    [GeneratePinDetail]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Random

For a random number, you can use `ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % range + lowerbound`:
(source: [How do I generate random number for each row in a TSQL Select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045138/how-do-i-generate-random-number-for-each-row-in-a-tsql-select))

```
INSERT INTO ResultsTable (PinDetailId, PinNo)
SELECT PinDetailId, 
       (ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % 1000000 + 1000000) AS `PinNo`
FROM GeneratePinDetail
ORDER BY PinDetailId ASC;
```

## Likely Not Unique

I cannot guarantee these will be unique; but it should be evenly distributed (equal chance of any 7 digit number). If you want to check for duplicates you can run this:

```
SELECT PinDetailId, PinNo 
FROM ResultsTable result
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT PinNo
    FROM ResultsTable
    GROUP BY PinNo
    HAVING Count(1) > 1
) test
ON result.PinNo = test.PinNo;
```

Comment: I need to update unique/random number not continue series. as per your example, I am getting continue value 1000000,1000001,1000002....

Comment: @TripurariYadav - Updated to be random... Unique and random are completely different things; ensuring both will be difficult without a recursive process. Are you sure you really need unique? That's not normal for a PIN/password; though it might be for an access token.

Comment: @ CodeConfident - fine, if it's not unique, but it should be a random number so that some one can not guess it.

Comment: @TripurariYadav - I added a query to check for duplicates... you might be able to eliminate the duplicates by regenerating just those rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a sequence object and update your fields - it should automatically increment per update.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/next-value-for-transact-sql

Updated based on comment:
After retrieving the 'next value for' in the sequence, you can do operations on it to randomize.  The sequence can basically be used then to create a unique seed for your randomization function.

If you don't want to create a function yourself, SQL Server has the RAND function build in already.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rand-transact-sql

Comment: I need random unique number, So no one can guess it.

Comment: @TripurariYadav - You should update your question... the request itself doesn't state random (even though your code implies it).