# UPDATE Statement with Randomly Assigned Values

Tags: t-sql, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to synthetically generate some seed values for a database. I have a list of employees and I want roughly 30% of them to be classified as "Minority" and the rest "Non-Minority", I thought that the following would work but it's classifying everyone as "Minority":

```
UPDATE datasetitems 
SET minority = CASE WHEN (FLOOR(RAND()*(10-1+1)+1) > 3) 
THEN 'Minority' ELSE 'Non-Minority' END;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045138/how-do-i-generate-random-number-for-each-row-in-a-tsql-select

Comment: It is getting evaluated once.

Comment: @paparazzo Any guidance on how to evaluate it multiple times? Do I need a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you are trying to do `RAND()` will not work because it generates a single random value for the batch which is why you're not seeing any variance. To generate a ***random value for each row*** use:

```
ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())%<desired max random number>)
```

Note this sample data:

```
DECLARE @datasetitems TABLE (minority VARCHAR(20));
INSERT @datasetitems(minority)
SELECT TOP (10) NULL FROM sys.all_columns;

SELECT CASE ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())%2) WHEN 0 THEN 'minority' ELSE 'non-minority' END
FROM @datasetitems;
```

Returns:

```
------------
non-minority
non-minority
minority
minority
minority
non-minority
minority
non-minority
minority
minority
```

ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())%2) will return a 0 or 1 for each row meaning that you'll have a 50/50 chance that you'll return minority or non-minority. This logic:

```
SELECT CASE ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())%4) WHEN 0 THEN 'minority' ELSE 'non-minority' END
FROM @datasetitems;
```

... would mean that there's a 1 in 4 chance that "minority" will be returned and a 3 in 4 chance that "non-minority" is returned. To apply this logic to your update, your code would look like this:

```
UPDATE @datasetitems
SET minority = CASE ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())%2) WHEN 0 THEN 'minority' ELSE 'non-minority' END
FROM @datasetitems;
```