# SQL Multiple Inserts with RAND - how to change the RAND value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I've got a statement that inserts values into a table based on a random value and another value

```
INSERT INTO TRAINER_SYNC (Steps, TrainerId, SyncDate)
SELECT AverageSteps * (RAND()*(1.15-0.85)+0.85), Id, GETDATE()
FROM TRAINER
```

This works fine, but whenever two "Trainers" have the same "AverageSteps", the number inserted into the table is always the same.

For example, if all the trainers have average steps of `10000`, here is the result in the `TRAINER_SYNC` table

```
Id  TrainerId   SyncDate                    Steps
10  1           2018-10-20 18:42:16.407     9482
11  2           2018-10-20 18:42:16.407     9482
12  3           2018-10-20 18:42:16.407     9482
13  4           2018-10-20 18:42:16.407     9482
14  5           2018-10-20 18:42:16.407     9482
15  6           2018-10-20 18:42:16.407     9482
16  7           2018-10-20 18:42:16.407     9482
17  8           2018-10-20 18:42:16.407     9482
18  9           2018-10-20 18:42:16.407     9482
```

Is there a way to get the `RAND()` in the insert statement to be more... "random"? I'm not sure what it is called, but reset the initial seed so each iteration of the insert gives me a different random value?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045138/how-do-i-generate-random-number-for-each-row-in-a-tsql-select , at least for MS SQL Server

Comment: @mint What is the DBMS?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name a dumb as it sounds, I've never known what database product I've used... I've always just used SQL Server Management Studio, but I'm guessing that I am using `sql-server`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rand()` is a special class of function that is evaluated exactly once for each call in the SQL statement.  This can be really confusing, because:

```
select rand(), rand()
```

returns two different values.  However,

```
select rand(), rand()
from (values (1), (2), (3)) v(x)
```

returns three rows -- with the same two values on each of the rows.  This is an optimization "feature" of SQL Server.  I believe that `getdate()` (and similar date/time functions) are the only other functions with this behavior.

The normal solution is to seed the random number generator with `newid()`.  But, the return types are different, so `checksum()` is used to convert the `id` to a number:

```
INSERT INTO TRAINER_SYNC (Steps, TrainerId, SyncDate)
    SELECT AverageSteps * (RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))*(1.15-0.85)+0.85), 
           Id, GETDATE()
    FROM TRAINER;
```

You could use a different seed, if one is available.  For instance, if only one row is going in per trainer, you could use `rand(id)`.  I should note that `rand()` is not particularly "random" with seeds, so adjacent seeds often produce similar numbers.

You probably should not be setting `GETDATE()` in the `INSERT`.  You can create the table with:

```
SyncDate datetime default getdate()
```

So the default value is the insertion time.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

1)
 `RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))`

OR

2)

```
INSERT INTO TRAINER_SYNC (Steps, TrainerId, SyncDate)
    SELECT AverageSteps * (RAND(AverageSteps)*(1.15-0.85)+0.85), Id, GETDATE()
    FROM TRAINER
```