# How can I get a random number generated in a CTE not to change in JOIN?

Tags: sql, sql-server, random, common-table-expression

**The problem**

I'm generating a random number for each row in a table `#Table_1` in a CTE, using [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045138/how-do-i-generate-random-number-for-each-row-in-a-tsql-select/1045162#1045162). I'm then joining the results of the CTE on another table, `#Table_2`. Instead of getting a random number for each row in `#Table_1`, I'm getting a new random number for every resulting row in the join!

```
CREATE TABLE #Table_1 (Id INT)

CREATE TABLE #Table_2 (MyId INT, ParentId INT)

INSERT INTO #Table_1
VALUES (1), (2), (3)

INSERT INTO #Table_2
VALUES (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2), (1, 3)


;WITH RandomCTE AS
(
    SELECT Id, (ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % 5)RandomNumber
    FROM #Table_1
)
SELECT r.Id, t.MyId, r.RandomNumber
FROM RandomCTE r
INNER JOIN #Table_2 t
    ON r.Id = t.ParentId
```

**The results**

```
Id          MyId        RandomNumber
----------- ----------- ------------
1           1           1
1           2           2
1           3           0
1           4           3
2           1           4
2           2           0
2           3           0
3           1           3
```

**The desired results**

```
Id          MyId        RandomNumber
----------- ----------- ------------
1           1           1
1           2           1
1           3           1
1           4           1
2           1           4
2           2           4
2           3           4
3           1           3
```

**What I tried**

I tried to obscure the logic of the random number generation from the optimizer by casting the random number to `VARCHAR`, but that did not work.

**What I don't want to do**

I'd like to avoid using a temporary table to store the results of the CTE.

How can I generate a random number for a table and preserve that random number in a join without using temporary storage?

Comment: Your query should return 4 columns, not 3. Two columns from `RandomCTE` and two columns from `Table_2`.

Comment: Interesting problem. May I ask why you don't want to use a temp table? I mean, tempdb is used for all sorts of things... and are you trying to force a *different* random number for each ID in table 1?

Comment: @TheImpaler You’re right, fixed

Comment: @scsimon I solved it with a temp table but I’m looking for a cleaner solution

Comment: the temp table *is* the cleanest solution. Rather than bending your SQL into strange shapes trying to workaround the optimiser and getting a result not guaranteed to always behave as you want

Answer (score 2):

This seems to do the trick:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT Id, (ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % 5)RandomNumber
    FROM #Table_1),
RandomCTE AS(
    SELECT Id,
           RandomNumber
    FROM CTE
    GROUP BY ID, RandomNumber)
SELECT *
FROM RandomCTE r
INNER JOIN #Table_2 t
    ON r.Id = t.ParentId;
```

It looks like SQL Server is aware that, at the point of being outside the CTE, that `RandomNumber` is effectively just `NEWID()` with some additional functions wrapped around it ([DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a9d18260d6cec034de63669788e68a49)), and hence it still generates a unique ID for each row. The `GROUP BY` clause in the second CTE therefore forces the data engine to define RandomNumber a value so it can perform the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: interesting though I'm betting they want each ID in table 1 to have it's own unique number, that doesn't overlap other IDs.

Comment: I hope not, @scsimon , as stopping the reuse of a random number would be **awfully** messy. And means that the number isn't truly "random" any more. *"pick a number between 1-5"* and *"pick a number between 1-5, but you can't have 1,2,3, or 5 because they've been chosen"* isn't a very random choice at all. I can say for certainty that you'll pick "4". :)

Comment: Nope, I’m looking for a truly random pick. The fact that they didn’t overlap in my desired results example was, well, random.

Comment: oh i don't disagree, i'm just basing off that *expected result* where the random number is for each ID. With a temp table, each ID could only have 1 number, and this would make sense for the OP. Looks like you nailed it Larnu.

Comment: It will continue to work until in SQL Server 2023 optimiser becomes smart enough to realise that `SELECT Col1, Col2 FROM T GROUP BY Col1, Col2` can be optimised away...

Comment: or a unique index is added to Col1 with current optimiser. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c723616c650626f5cfbcfb9bc0dc7350

Answer (score 2):

Per the quote in [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/30348/3690)

> The optimizer does not guarantee timing or number of executions of
>   scalar functions. This is a long-estabilished tenet. It's the
>   fundamental 'leeway' tha allows the optimizer enough freedom to gain
>   significant improvements in query-plan execution.

If it is important for your application that the random number be evaluated once and only once you should calculate it up front and store it into a temp table.

Anything else is not guaranteed and so is irresponsible to add into your application's code base - as even if it works now it may break as a result of a schema change/execution plan change/version upgrade/CU install.

For example Lamu's answer breaks if a unique index is added to `#Table_1 (Id)`

Answer (score 0):

How about not using a real random number at all?  Use `rand()` with a seed:

```
WITH RandomCTE AS (
      SELECT Id,
             CONVERT(INT, RAND(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()) * 999999) * 5) as RandomNumber
      FROM #Table_1
     )
SELECT r.Id, t.MyId, r.RandomNumber
FROM RandomCTE rINNER JOIN
     #Table_2 t
     ON r.Id = t.ParentId;
```

The seed argument to `rand()` is pretty awful.  Values of the seed near each other produce similar initial values, which is the reason for the multiplication.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1f0df9a286f97af955b2ba297e5bc429) is the db<>fiddle.

Comment: Does this have a practical effect on how random the number is?

Comment: @elizabk . . . Unfortunately, it does.  If you remove the multiplication, you get the same number for low ids.  You can check that the random value is returning different values -- but they are very close together.