# Applying a random column value to existing data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a little difficulty with SQL Server 2017.

We are creating a database for benchmarks of our software, the database consists of data such as people's home addressees, phone numbers and such. The problem I have is as follows:

I have several columns already filled with data. Now I have house numbers ranging from 1-100. And I am supposed to write a script that will insert a random number from that range if the home address is identical. So, if for e example "Baloon Street' occurs 2 times, then a random 2 numbers would be inserted, separate for each Baloon Street.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: maybe this [how-do-i-generate-random-number-for-each-row-in-a-tsql-select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045138/how-do-i-generate-random-number-for-each-row-in-a-tsql-select) will help

Comment: abs(checksum(newid())%100)+1. It gives random value from 1 to 100.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I generate random number for each row in a TSQL Select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045138/how-do-i-generate-random-number-for-each-row-in-a-tsql-select)