# Generating stable random numbers in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working in SQL Server 2012. I'm cleaning data, and am trying to break ties in an address-assigning algorithm randomly. This requires me to generate random numbers. The approach taken by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045138/how-do-i-generate-random-number-for-each-row-in-a-tsql-select#) doesn't work because the WITH subquery seems to regenerate each side of the join, resulting in different random numbers for the same row.

This code replicates the problem:

```
WITH
initial_table AS (
    SELECT 1 AS id
),
random_values_added AS (
  SELECT id, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 10 AS rand
  FROM initial_table
)
SELECT t1.id, t2,id, t1.rand, t2.rand
FROM random_values_added t1 FULL OUTER JOIN random_values_added t2
ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.rand = t2.rand
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the CTE is run dynamically, when you call the join condition, you can store the intermediate results in a temporary table and leverage it for your query.

```
WITH
initial_table AS (
    SELECT 1 AS id
    union all
    SELECT 2
),
random_values_added AS (
  SELECT id, newid() AS rand
  FROM initial_table
)
select * into #RANDTable FROM random_values_added


SELECT t1.id, t2.id, t1.rand, t2.rand
FROM #RANDTable t1 
FULL OUTER JOIN #RANDTable t2
ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.rand = t2.rand
```

```
+----+----+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| id | id |                 rand                 |                 rand                 |
+----+----+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
|  1 |  1 | 3E366071-CD5A-4B1F-A043-831FE13B7102 | 3E366071-CD5A-4B1F-A043-831FE13B7102 |
|  2 |  2 | CC53C2F8-1C06-4BD8-8111-7133B45F4B79 | CC53C2F8-1C06-4BD8-8111-7133B45F4B79 |
+----+----+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a trick using `rand()`.  Assuming that `id` is unique, you can start with:

```
WITH initial_table AS (
      SELECT 1 AS id
     ),
     random_values_added AS (
      SELECT id, FLOOR(RAND(id) * 10) AS rand
      FROM initial_table
    )
```

This is not totally satisfying because it returns the same value every time the code is run.  For that, we can use the fact that `getdate()` is evaluated once per query:

```
WITH initial_table AS (
      SELECT 1 AS id
     ),
     random_values_added AS (
      SELECT id, FLOOR(RAND(DATEADD(second, id, GETDATE()) * 10) AS rand
      FROM initial_table
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try removing the self join?

```
  SELECT id, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 10 AS rand
  FROM your_table
```

Can you also try the `rand()` function if it works in SQL Server 2012?