# SQL Server : generate random numeric string 27 characters long

Tags: sql-server, string, random, numeric

I need to insert random data in my database for testing, and would need to generate a numeric string (can start with 0) 27 characters long.

I've been looking into `NEWID()` but it contains also letters, same for `NEWSEQUENTIALID()`.

So far my approach would be to make a while loop, generate each digit randomly and concatenate it, but it seems to be a very slow approach.

I am using MSSQL 2014.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045138/how-do-i-generate-a-random-number-for-each-row-in-a-t-sql-select) answer your question?

Comment: @Zhorov, no because it generates a single small integer that is up to 2 characters long. not 27.

Comment: select it from a `TALLY` table with the required number of digits and `STRING_AGG()` it

Comment: I'll offer this, but not as an answer, since then I'd be required to explain and defend it -- `select right(replicate('0', 27) + convert(decimal(38, 0), 0x26000001 + crypt_gen_random(13)), 27)`. This approach cannot generate arbitrarily long values, but it's likely to be faster than anything else (where such things matter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution, based on this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045138/how-do-i-generate-a-random-number-for-each-row-in-a-t-sql-select) (using `CHECKSUM()` and `NEWID()`):

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable(RandomNumber varchar(27))
DECLARE @length int = 27

;WITH rCTE AS (
   SELECT 1 AS n 
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT n + 1 
   FROM rCTE 
   WHERE n < @length
)
INSERT INTO TestTable(RandomNumber)
VALUES ((SELECT ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 10 FROM rCTE FOR XML PATH('')))
-- For SQL Server 2017+
-- VALUES ((SELECT STRING_AGG(ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 10, '') FROM rCTE))
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I am on MsSql 2014 and that does not have the STRING_AGG function. I add this information to the post

Comment: thank you, but how can I add this result to a insert statement? I tried but got the message that FOR XML is not allowed in an insert statement.