# Generate random number between 0.85 and 0.95 for each row in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, random, numbers, case

I'd like to generate a random number between 0.85 and 0.95 for each row.

At first I tried using (rand()*(0.85-0.95)+0.95) but the same number was generated for every single row.

My query looks like something like this:

```
select
case when x=1 then (rand()*(0.85-0.95)+0.95) else 0
from abcd
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I generate a random number for each row in a T-SQL select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045138/how-do-i-generate-a-random-number-for-each-row-in-a-t-sql-select)

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6ceb09e733b44820c7c45e7180aa9d67

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RAND()` returns the same number for a given statement. A solution would be to use `NEWID()`. Something like:

`CONVERT( DECIMAL(2, 2), .85 + (.95 - .85 )*RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())))`

Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cd1ed55dc954b9a93a278662fb723155)

Comment: Pedantry is the spice of life. I've updated it to statement.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use NEWID for generating random numbers; as RAND() will give same values for all rows in the table as seed does not change. We can use NEWID to feed new seed values per row and get a diff random number.

so your case condition is more like

```
 (RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))*(0.85-0.95)+0.95)
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2f37128d33ff1234017b108a10da7e37)

and your query like

```
select
case when x=1 then (RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))*(0.85-0.95)+0.95) else 0
from abcd
```