# Insert a value restricted to upper and lower bounds

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to do an insert where one column is to be a calculated numerical value based on a value from another table, yet restricted between upper and lower bounds. Let's call these `@lower_bounds` and `@upper_bounds` (such that `@lower_bounds < @upper_bounds`).

So I might, as an example, want to do something like this:

```sql
INSERT o.[one_value] * (some calculation) AS [value]
INTO [table]
FROM [other_table] AS o
```

However, `[value]` must never be higher or lower than the bounds. So if the calculated `[value] < @lower_bounds`, then I need `[value] = @lower_bounds` instead.

And if `[value] > @upper_bounds`, then I need `[value] = @upper_bounds`.

The problem for me is having to do a unique calculation per row and not just pick the *lowest* between the result and a certain number, but *also* to pick the *highest* between the result and a certain other number *at the same time*.

Is there an easy way to do this in T-SQL? (There's a lot of data and cost has to be kept reasonably low.)

Comment: what type is `o.[big_value]`

Comment: What about limiting the random value to the exact bounds you need, e.g. as `boundedValue = lowerBound + randomValue * (upperBound - lowerBound) / maximumRandomValue` (integer division assumed, otherwise you might need to round)?

Comment: @Aconcagua That is what I assume Thom A meant when closing as duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045138/how-do-i-generate-a-random-number-for-each-row-in-a-t-sql-select. It should however give a different value distribution. The OP specifically mentions that there is a `(small normally distributed random component calculated here)`, clamping that inside the final range will squeeze the entire distribution curve by the X axis instead of cutting it off on the edges.