# Randomize values in SQL Server using extra criteria

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, random, checksum, newid

[image]

I need to **update** the Amount column with a randomized values for every row present in the above table.

However, there are a few rules that I need to meet for this:

- For TransactionType = Deposit, the **randomized value must be between $10 and $20.**
- For everything else, the randomized value **MUST be between between $0.01 and $1** **AND** **LESS OR EQUAL than the original Amount** that we are randomizing.

So for example for ID = 7 the randomized value must be between $0.01 and $0.80.

I am struggling to get the results I want with the RAND, CHECKSUM, NEWID functions.
Sometimes even getting 0 (zero) as a randomized value for some reason.

This is in SQL Server.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Does this answer your qusetion? [How do I generate a random number for each row in a T-SQL select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045138/how-do-i-generate-a-random-number-for-each-row-in-a-t-sql-select)

Comment: It did help me in using the correct functions but I am still unable to meet the criteria I mentioned in the original post.

Comment: for deposit why between 1 and 20. i can see the logic in that

Comment: So what isn't working about your attempt, @thatsweetguy ? What *is* that attempt?

Comment: @nbk it was a type. For deposits it should be between 10 and 20, not 1 and 20. Corrected it now.

Comment: @ThomA UPDATE a SET a.RecordedAmount = case when RecordedTransaction = 'Deposit' THEN FLOOR(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * (20-10) + 1) ELSE CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 0.99 AS FLOAT) + 0.01
FROM dbo.MyTable a

That's my attempt, however it's not meeting either the criteria for the deposit nor for the randomized amounts being less than the original amount.

Comment: [Edit] your question with the attempt(s), @thatsweetguy , and explain why they don't work. Also we still need some sample data (images do not count).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to add another cast to check if the amount is smaller than the 0.99

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
  ID INTEGER,
  UserID INTEGER,
  RecordedTransaction VARCHAR(8),
  RecordedAmount FLOAT
);

INSERT INTO MyTable
  (ID, UserID, RecordedTransaction, RecordedAmount)
VALUES
  ('1', '12345678', 'Purchase', '0.10'),
  ('2', '12345678', 'Deposit', '100.00'),
  ('3', '12345678', 'Purchase', '100.00'),
  ('4', '12345678', 'Deposit', '30.00'),
  ('5', '12345678', 'Purchase', '30.00'),
  ('6', '12345678', 'Deposit', '25.00'),
  ('7', '12345678', 'Purchase', '0.80');
```

```
7 rows affected
```

```
 UPDATE a 
 SET a.RecordedAmount = case when RecordedTransaction = 'Deposit' THEN 
   FLOOR(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))* (20- 10 + 1)) + 10 
 ELSE ROUND(
 (CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 
 (CASE WHEN  RecordedAmount < 0.99 THEN RecordedAmount ELSE 0.99 END) AS FLOAT) + 0.01 )
 ,2,0) end
 FROM dbo.MyTable a
```

```
7 rows affected
```

```
SELECT * fROM MyTable
```

| ID | UserID | RecordedTransaction | RecordedAmount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12345678 | Purchase | 0.07 |
| 2 | 12345678 | Deposit | 20 |
| 3 | 12345678 | Purchase | 0.41 |
| 4 | 12345678 | Deposit | 18 |
| 5 | 12345678 | Purchase | 0.03 |
| 6 | 12345678 | Deposit | 17 |
| 7 | 12345678 | Purchase | 0.1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XBgWfJiH)

#m with DECIMAL as Datatype it get a bit easier

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
  ID INTEGER,
  UserID INTEGER,
  RecordedTransaction VARCHAR(8),
  RecordedAmount DECIMAL(10,2)
);

INSERT INTO MyTable
  (ID, UserID, RecordedTransaction, RecordedAmount)
VALUES
  ('1', '12345678', 'Purchase', '0.10'),
  ('2', '12345678', 'Deposit', '100.00'),
  ('3', '12345678', 'Purchase', '100.00'),
  ('4', '12345678', 'Deposit', '30.00'),
  ('5', '12345678', 'Purchase', '30.00'),
  ('6', '12345678', 'Deposit', '25.00'),
  ('7', '12345678', 'Purchase', '0.80');
```

```
7 rows affected
```

```
 UPDATE a 
 SET a.RecordedAmount = 
   case when RecordedTransaction = 'Deposit' THEN FLOOR(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * (20 - 10 + 1) + 10) 
 ELSE 
 (CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 
 (CASE WHEN  RecordedAmount < 0.99 THEN RecordedAmount ELSE 0.99 END) AS FLOAT) + 0.01 )
  end
 FROM dbo.MyTable a
```

```
7 rows affected
```

```
SELECT * fROM MyTable
```

| ID | UserID | RecordedTransaction | RecordedAmount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12345678 | Purchase | 0.02 |
| 2 | 12345678 | Deposit | 10.00 |
| 3 | 12345678 | Purchase | 0.41 |
| 4 | 12345678 | Deposit | 16.00 |
| 5 | 12345678 | Purchase | 0.98 |
| 6 | 12345678 | Deposit | 11.00 |
| 7 | 12345678 | Purchase | 0.56 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OtTb984I)

Comment: A `float` feels like a poor data type choice for something that appears to be a monetary value.

Comment: yes @ThomA but he convert the value to float so my guess is that it is a float datatyoe, i would take a decimal but it wouldn't change anything it would still work, but you can skip then round part

Comment: @nbk Thank you. I just tested it but noticed two problems with it.. even though the randomized value for the Deposit is between the range 10 to 20, it is the same value across all rows. The randomized rows for the remaining transactions isn't always less than the original amount - I have tested this with a "Purchase" transaction of 0.10 and the randomized value was 0.11.

Comment: i changed the second to be actually random, i too that you tested your code